# How to get comments other than using wp_list_comments?

Tags: comments

I'm sure you guys are wondering, "why the hell?" - basically it is because it does not work with a plugin by NextSCRIPTS that pulls comments from facebook.  When I'm in the admin panel I see the comments properly, but on the blog posts it just keeps showing the admin instead of the users.  This happened after updating to 3.6, NextSCRIPTS told me they are aware of this issue but it has been one month and we have over 8,000 comments and I'd like to find a work around.

So really, you don't need any code from me, just please if anyone knows, can you share how to grab the comments without using wp_list_comments?  there has to be another way.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Can't you restore previous plugin version until they fix the bug? Maybe there are a lot of different ways to get comments, but without knowing what cause the issue it's impossible to be sure alternative way will not cause it too.

Comment: @GM, would rather do a workaround at this point but good idea.  As far as it being impossible to be sure that is true!  But nothing ventured, nothing gained ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a labor intensive workaround but [`get_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) is probably what you want.

From the Codex:

```
$comments = get_comments('post_id=15');
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author);
endforeach;
```

There is also [`WP_Comment_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you good sir. This worked. http://www.hvac-hacks.com